# How to add a highlight in cycle Toon BSDF?

Tags: rendering

I used to use Eevee to made toon shader. but the cycle has higher quilty so I start to switch to cycles. [image]
This is what I get.
I want to add a high light like this [image]

Comment: Hello - you asked a similar question before - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237359/how-to-add-glow-in-toon-shader/237361#237361 - What is happening differently from the eevee version that you would like to fix? Toon shaders aren't as "tight" in cycles, by nature.

Comment: I use the same nodes but the result is different. So I am confused.

Comment: Yeah, that last line I just added to my first comment explains it - toon shading works vastly differently in cycles (different end-result). Let me try a couple things. FYI - if you are looking for the "glow" (bloom), this must be done in compositing in cycles.